# How to toggle a class immediately upon click (not after mouse button is released)

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggleclass

I'd like to change the color of my span element **immediately** when the user clicks on it - not have the color change occur after the mouse button is released.

Here's my CSS for the class I'm toggling:

```
span.active{
  color:#bdbcae;
}
```

Here's my "idea" for the jQuery, but this toggles the class after the click:

```
$("span").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

It's probably something basic, or maybe something more complex, but what kind of function do I use to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you should try `mousedown` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mousedown`

```
$("span").mousedown(function() {
```

API Ref: http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Answer (score 2):

mousedown sounds like what you're looking for:

http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

so this would probably be your code:

```
$( "span" ).mousedown(function() {
   $( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
});
```